# Did Fantus die during the destruction of Krondor during the Serpentwar Saga?

Tags: magical-creatures, riftwar-cycle

In the earlier novels, Fantus is attached to William.  William died during the destruction of Krondor, but I don't recall whether Fantus was ever mentioned again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he did not die and he is mentioned in later books continuing his trans-dimensional journey to godhood.  After review, I may be thinking of Macros, it's been a good decade and change since I read the novels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The fate of Fantus was never resolved.**

**From the [Midkemia Wiki](http://midkemia.wikia.com/wiki/Fantus):**

> Fantus starts out as the companion of Kulgan where they both live at Crydee, when Pug becomes apprenticed to Kulgan and he begins spending more time at the Crydee castle Fantus becomes well known by all at Crydee (although some still find his appearance unnerving like Carline conDoin) as he often stops by the kitchen for food scraps.
>
> Later during the riftwar Fantus finds his way to the Kingdom staging point in order to become reacquainted with Kulgan. It is here he meets William son of Pug who he becomes a close companion of in later years.
>
> When Kulgan and Pug move to Stardock to start the Magician Academy, Fantus also moves with them and he is seen frequently with William who is later revealed is able to talk to him as part of his magical abilities.
>
> After William's death, Fantus disappeared, and his location is currently unknown.

**From the Crydee Website where Raymond Feist regularly appeared:**

> [**Where is or what happened to Fantus the Fire Drake?**](http://www.crydee.com/raymond-feist/faq/9194/where-is-or-what-happened-to-fantus-the-fire-drake)
>
> From: Raymond E. Feist
>
> Date: 24 September 2008
>
> I never revealed it. In short, I didn't think I could come up what a decent "and then he got old, found a little cave and crawled off to die," from anyone's point of view. I think letting him fade from the scene after William got older was just a little more realistic. It's like when the family cat wanders off and you never see him again. You don't know if he found another house with better food, was munched by a coyote, hit by a car, etc.
>
> Best, R.E.F.

The Riftwar Saga and the Daughter of the Empire Series are my favorite fantasy sagas ever written. Raymond Feist and Janny Wurts brought the series alive when they collaborated over Midkemia and Kelewan.